# Default port for calls with Asterisk

Tags: port, sip, asterisk

I have AsteriskNOW 11.9.0 with FreePBX 2.11.0.43. I moved Asterisk to a non-standard port number, but now I can call extensions only if I specify the port number explicitly in a callee's number, for example 101@myasterisk.net:5555

How to avoid this? Ideally, when dialing, I would like to dial only the number which comes before @. Where should this be configured? In Asterisk? In SIP client?

I am using MicroSIP (Windows) and CSipSimple (Android) clients and all of them require port number when dialing. A normal SIP client, I think, should use automatically the same port number as it is using to access Asterisk. I could not believe that such popular SIP clients could be so inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the SIP client you are using.
Most SIP clients allows you to configure the SIP server in its settings (myasterisk.net:5555) and then just use the username part (101) when you dial.

Comment: I am using MicroSIP and CSipSimple and all of them require port number.